# Find the path from leaf to root in Tree

Tags: java

I saw a lot of examples about Trees and how to recursively search them, but not like my case. So I decide to ask.

How can I find a path from any leaf to the root?

My problem is that I have a lot of child nodes per parent. Here is an example of my code:

```
 private LinkedList<TreeNode> findPath(LinkedList<TreeNode> path, TreeNode root, TreeNode leaf){
    if(root == null || root.name==null) return null;

    path.add(root);

    if(root.name.equals(leaf.name))
        return path;

    //Check if the leaf that we are looking for is one of the root children
    if(root.children==null) return null;
    for(TreeNode children : root.children){
        if(children.name.equals(leaf.name)){
            path.add(children);
            return path;
        }
    }
    //Search in all the childrens of the root recursively
    for(TreeNode children : root.children){
        LinkedList<TreeNode> result =  findPath(path, children, leaf);
        if(result != null)
            return result;
    }

    //The leaf is not found. 
    return null;
}
```

And the problem is that every time when I check a child, if I don't find my leaf there I take back but I have add the child node in the path and my path becomes very big.

Answer (score 2):

This implementation assumes that every tree node 'knows' its parent:

```
private List<TreeNode> findPath(TreeNode root, TreeNode leaf) {
    List<TreeNode> path = new ArrayList<>();
    TreeNode node = leaf;
    do {
        path.add(node);
        node = node.getParent();
    } while (node != root);

    return path;
}
```

Of course you should add validity check for root and leaf and think of the possibility of an infinite loop if a node is (directly or indirectly) its own parent.

If your tree nodes only contain their children, but a child node does not 'know' its parent (which you probably should change if you own the code of the tree nodes), its getting more complex, as the tree must be searched recursively:

```
public static List<TreeNode> findPath(TreeNode root, TreeNode leaf) {
    LinkedList<TreeNode> path = new LinkedList<>();
    findPathHelper(root, leaf, path);
    return path;
}

private static boolean findPathHelper(TreeNode root, TreeNode leaf, List<TreeNode> path) {
    if (root == leaf) {
        path.add(root);
        return true;
    }

    for (TreeNode treeNode : root.children) {
        if (findPathHelper(treeNode, leaf, path)) {
            path.add(root);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is that even possible, building a structure from `TreeNode`s that's not actually a tree?

Comment: @G.Bach what do you mean? I'm just creating an ArrayList and fill it with pre-existing TreeNodes.

Comment: You said "Of course you should add validity check for root and leaf and think of the possibility of an infinite loop if a node is (directly or indirectly) its own parent." I wonder if that is even possible, because that would make the structure of `TreeNode`s not a tree.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but I don't know the parent of the node. That's why I'm having trouble with finding the path. The only way is from the root to start iterating until I find the leaf and save the path to it. But I'm having problems of implementing this logic.

Comment: @user2883938 As you did not give any detailed information about your TreeNode class, I was assuming that you're either using javax.swing.tree.TreeNode or any other node class that 'knows' its parent.

Comment: @user2883938 I've added an algorithm that finds the path by traversing the children instead of walking up via parents.